# Should I rename subsequent BuildContexts inside a Flutter widget

Tags: flutter

To be more precise, are there any errors or complications that might occur if I have multiple variables named "context" inside a Widgets build methode. For example, if i have a Builder Widget inside my build function, it will pass down a "new" context, which will automatically get used by subsequent widgets in the widget tree (as far as I understand).

```
  @override 
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Center(
      child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 80.0, horizontal: 24.0),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Text(
          FlutterI18n.translate(context, 'introduction.slide2.title'),
          style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, fontSize: TextSize.extraLarge),
        ),
        Text(FlutterI18n.translate(context, 'introduction.slide2.content'), style: TextStyle(fontSize: TextSize.large)),
        ValueListenableBuilder(
          valueListenable: status,
          builder: (context, permission, child) {
            return ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: permission == PermissionStatus.granted ? null : _requestBatteryOptimizationPermission,
                child: Text(FlutterI18n.translate(context, 'introduction.slide2.button'),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: TextSize.large)));
          },
        )
      ],
    ),
  )),
);
}
```

In this example, I have my **context** provided by the build methode, as well as a new **context** introduced by the ValueListenableBuilder. In my code base there are also build methods which introduce two or three contexts inside.

So, should I rename them like "ctx" or "context1", "context2", etc., or does it not matter?

Comment: You're right, variable in the inner scope will [shadow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the outer one

Comment: You might only need to rename inner Contexts of you intend to use the Parent's Context in a Child Widget, unless the code and debugging can work flawlessly. For Example you need to Query the dimentions of a parent widget in a child widget, you will need both widgets' `BuildContext`s, with distinct names.

Comment: If you're not using the inner context at all, you can also just use some number of underscores as the normal convention for "throwaway variable".

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter since your context is a variable which is scoped between the brackets. If you command click on your variable you will jump to the correct definition.

But it makes sense to rename it for yourself or your team since it can become confusing if you have a context from your build, a context inside a dialog, a context inside a builder, etc.